# How i can make these divs go next to each other

Tags: html, css

What it looks like:

[image]

I want the white div go below the grey div and so that the green div doesnt go anywhere..

This is my code at this moment.

```
#top {

background-color:#504A4B;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
width:500px;
height:200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
}

#middle {
background-color:#D1D0CE;
width:100px;
height:500px;
margin-left:36.8%;
margin-right:auto;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
position:static;
clear: both;
}

#left {
background-color:#25383C;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
width:75px;
height:75px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
clear:both
```

Comment: Is this homework ? Align a div beside another ?

Comment: Why don't you post a picture of what it should look like... when is the homework due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the green div `position:absolute` and position it with `top` and `left`. This way you can position it independently of the grey and white divs.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
clear:both;
```

and add

```
float: left;
```

to both #middle and #left

that should give you an idea

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XgZE9/)

OR

add

```
position:absolute
```

to div#left